# How to remove characters from specific index in String?

Tags: rust

I have an application where I am receiving a string with some repetitive characters. I am receiving input as a String. How to remove the characters from specific index?

main.rs

```
fn main() {
    let s:String = "{\"name\":\"xx/yyyy/machine/zzz/test_int4\",\"status\":\"online\",\"timestamp\":\"2021-06-11 18:20:42.231770800 UTC\",\"value\":7}8668982856274}".to_string();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

how can I get result

```
"{\"name\":\"xx/yyyy/machine/zzz/test_int4\",\"status\":\"online\",\"timestamp\":\"2021-06-11 18:20:42.231770800 UTC\",\"value\":7}"
```

instead of

```
"{\"name\":\"xx/yyyy/machine/zzz/test_int4\",\"status\":\"online\",\"timestamp\":\"2021-06-11 18:20:42.231770800 UTC\",\"value\":7}}8668982856274}"
```

Comment: @trentcl  I have edited my question with rust file. I hope its easy to understand now.

Comment: If you know the index, you could just use the slice indexing notation: `s[..index]`.  However your problem appears not to be the question you’ve asked (how to remove characters from specific index), but rather how to find the index given the input string—and that requires a deeper understanding of your requirements.  Are you ultimately trying to parse the input string as a JSON object, discarding any trailing characters?

Comment: @eggyal Are you ultimately trying to parse the input string as a JSON object, discarding any trailing characters? yes that is the goal. The problem is string length can very so I was using .find method which gives usize as a position for "}" character but then its not allowing for indexing as method is not implemented on String. I am trying to find something inbuilt can do this characters removal easily. So yes 1) I want to remove anything after first appearance of char "}". then 2) Convert that new string to json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String indexing works only with bytes, thus you need to find an index for the appropriate byte slice like this:

```rust
let mut s = "{\"name\":\"xx/yyyy/machine/zzz/test_int4\",\"status\":\"online\",\"timestamp\":\"2021-06-11 18:20:42.231770800 UTC\",\"value\":7}8668982856274}";
let closing_bracket_idx = s
    .as_bytes()
    .iter()
    .position(|&x| x == b'}')
    .map(|i| i + 1)
    .unwrap_or_else(|| s.len());
let v: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&s[..closing_bracket_idx]).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", v);
```

However, keep in mind, this approach doesn't really work in general for more complex cases, for example `}` in a json string value, or nested objects, or a type other than an object at the upmost level (e.g. `[1, {2: 3}, 4]`). More neat way is using parser capabilities to ignore of the trailing, as an example for serde_json:

```rust
let v = serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(s)
    .into_iter::<serde_json::Value>()
    .next()
    .expect("empty input")
    .expect("invalid json value");
println!("{:?}", v);
```